# How to looping 2 div and only contain 2 content/article/news

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

iam create website use template,
but i'm confused **while loop / for loop** one of script this template

this loop 
2 div but only contain 2 content/article/news

**This screenshot**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OHsV.png

**This code**

```
<?php 
$data_news = mysql_query("select * from news");
while($news=mysql_fetch_object($data_news)){
?>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <ul>
                      <li class="clearfix">
                        <div class="scale_image_container">
                          <a href="#"><img src="images/flex_small_img1.jpg" alt="" class="scale_image"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post_text">
                          <a href="#"><h4><?php echo $news->title ?></h4></a>
                        <div class="event_date"><?php echo tgl($news->datenews) ?></div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="clearfix">
                        <div class="scale_image_container">
                          <a href="#"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" class="scale_image"></a>
                        </div>
                       <div class="post_text">
                          <a href="#"><h4><?php echo $news->title ?></h4></a>
                        <div class="event_date"><?php echo tgl($news->datenews) ?></div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>


<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                    <ul>
                      <li class="clearfix">
                        <div class="scale_image_container">
                          <a href="#"><img src="images/flex_small_img1.jpg" alt="" class="scale_image"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post_text">
                          <a href="#"><h4><?php echo $news->title ?></h4></a>
                        <div class="event_date"><?php echo tgl($news->datenews) ?></div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li class="clearfix">
                        <div class="scale_image_container">
                          <a href="#"><img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" class="scale_image"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post_text">
                          <a href="#"><h4><?php echo $news->title ?></h4></a>
                        <div class="event_date"><?php echo tgl($news->datenews) ?></div>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
       </div>
<?php } ?>
```

How i can **while loop/for loop** like my this screenshot ?

Thank's :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1you can use something like this , please try

```
<?php 
$data_news = mysql_query("select * from news");
$count=1;
while($news=mysql_fetch_object($data_news)){
?>

        <?php if($count % 2!=0 ) {?>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <ul>
                <?php } ?>

                  <li class="clearfix">
                    <div class="scale_image_container">
                      <a href="#"><img src="images/flex_small_img1.jpg" alt="" class="scale_image"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post_text">
                      <a href="#"><h4><?php echo $news->title ?></h4></a>
                    <div class="event_date"><?php echo tgl($news->datenews) ?></div>
                    </div>
                  </li>

            <?php if($count % 2==0) {?>
                </ul></div>
                <?php } ?>

 <?php  $count++;} ?>
```

Comment: Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '='  


this code 


  <?php if($count % 2=0 || $count==1) {?>
                            <div>


but i change like this

  <?php if($count % 2==0 || $count==1) {?>
                            <div>
                    <?php } ?>


 <?php $count++; } ?>

this result while  like this -_-
http://i.imgur.com/aJlxSSm.png

Comment: can you giv me the link??

Comment: im using localhost, im buy this template this link > http://velikorodnov.com/html/revija/

this result same : http://i.imgur.com/aJlxSSm.png

if this code, i change "<div>" to "</div>"
  <?php if($count % 2!=0 || $count==1) {?> </div> <?php } ?>

this result like this : http://i.imgur.com/bydUu0z.png

Comment: I know while code your update john

this result have same field
screnshoot : http://i.imgur.com/HAf5Vc5.png